# How do I convert between MapProxy and MindMap in Freeplane?

Tags: freeplane

Using the scripting interface in Freeplane for groovy

```
import org.freeplane.plugin.script.proxy.MapProxy
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
import org.freeplane.api.MindMap

boolean overwriteExistingFile = true

String directory = 'data'
new File(directory).eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
  if(it.name.endsWith('.mm')) {
    MapProxy theMap = c.mapLoader(it.path).load()
    MindMap finalMind = theMap.delegate.getRootNode().map
    String filename = '/tmp/' + it.name.replaceFirst('.mm$', '.svg')
    c.export(finalMind,  filename, 'Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) (.svg)', overwriteExistingFile)
  }
}
```

Loading files from the file system gives me a MapProxy while the sample solution to this problem uses NodeProxy. The type passed to c.export for finalMind is supposed to be MindMap.

This is the sample, which works

```
boolean overwriteExistingFile = true
String filename = '/tmp/' + node.map.file.name.replaceFirst('.mm$', '.svg');
c.export(node.map, new File(filename), 'Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG)', overwriteExistingFile)
```

I've tried creating a scripting context to get NodeProxy.

```
import org.freeplane.api.NodeRO
import org.freeplane.plugin.script.NodeScript
import org.freeplane.plugin.script.ScriptContext
import org.freeplane.plugin.script.proxy.MapProxy
import org.freeplane.plugin.script.proxy.ProxyFactory

import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
import org.freeplane.api.MindMap

boolean overwriteExistingFile = true

String directory = '/Users/jrobens/NetBeansProjects/freeplane-scripting/'
new File(directory).eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
if(it.name.endsWith('.mm')) {
    MapProxy theMap = c.mapLoader(it.path).load()

    NodeScript nodeScript = new NodeScript(theMap.getDelegate().getRootNode(), "source");
    final ScriptContext scriptContext = new ScriptContext(nodeScript);
    NodeRO nodeProxy = ProxyFactory.createNode(theMap.getDelegate().getRootNode(), scriptContext);


 //   MindMap finalMind = theMap.getRoot().getMindMap()
    String filename = '/tmp/' + it.name.replaceFirst('.mm$', '.svg')

    MindMap losingMind = nodeProxy.getMindMap()
    c.export(nodeProxy.map,  filename, 'Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) (.svg)', overwriteExistingFile)
  }
}

// @ExecutionModes({ON_SELECTED_NODE, ON_SELECTED_NODE_RECURSIVELY})
```